# Can JMS single session have multiple MessageProducer?

Tags: java, jms

Can JMS single session have multiple `MessageProducer` and use each `MessageProducer` parallel?

for example:

```
p1= Session.createProducer(Queue1);
p2= Session.createProducer(Queue2);
thread1() {
p1.send();
}
thread2() {
p2.send();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: Please read JMS Specifications Chapter 2.8.

Answer (score 0):

Session, MessageProducer and MessageConsumer are not thread-safe. It is recommended to have separate Session for each thread.

You are trying to use same Session object in various threads. If you can't avoid it (can't think of such use case) you need to ensure thread safety by yourself (via standard java synchronization mechanisms).

Connection and ConnectionFactory are thread safe.